# Median,First Quartile and Third Quartile

Tags: statistics

[image: Stem and leaf diagram]

[image]
This is my attempts,

Median$=L+(\frac{\frac{1}{2}N-F}{fm})C$ where $L$ is the lower boundary for median class,$N$ is total frequency, $F$ is the cumulative frequency before the median class,$fm$ is the frequency of the median class and $C$ is the size of the class interval.

$=29.5+(\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot 51-3}{25})10$

$=38.5$

$Q_1=29.5+(\frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot 51-3}{25})10$

$=33.4$

$Q_3=39.5+(\frac{\frac{3}{4}\cdot 51-28}{15})10$

$46.3$

But the given answer for median is $38.7$, $Q_1=33.5$ and $Q_3=45.5$

Why? Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have actual values, or just intervals for your data? With 51 data points, you'd simply take the 26th highest value as your median.

Comment: I've actual values. I've uploaded the stem-and-leaf diagram in my post. @Bey

Comment: Then the median is just the 26th highest value...not sure why your answer is expected to be a decimal, you have an odd number of data points. Your 1st and 3rd quartile should be simply the median of values 1-25 and 26-50, respectively.

Comment: @Mathxx The value of your median looks right to me.

Comment: @Mathxx But I would calculate with L=30. (lower  limit of the median class).

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas for the  median and the quartiles look very strange, though the terms are not defined.  Your formulas take account the span of the data, which is not standard.  When you have an odd number of values, the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is just the middle value.  As you have $51$ values, the median would be the $26$th, which is $37$.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) gives three different definitions of quartiles, that differ slightly for distributions with few data points.  Method 1 would say the lower quartile is your $13$th data point, which is $32$ and the upper quartile is the $39$th, which is $45$

Comment: That's the formula for median for grouped data, where $L$ is the lower boundary for median class,$N$ is total frequency, $F$ is the cumulative frequency before the median class,$fm$ is the frequency of the median class and $C$ is the size of the class interval.

Comment: They are assuming that the data in the groups are evenly distributed in the group, which is where the formula comes from.  I agree with your arithmetic for the median.